# Is there a onViewDidReload()?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I use a `tabbarController`, having two tab-views and set the navbarTitle like this in my tabViews (in didViewLoad):

```
self.tabBarController?.title = "Title"
```

Now my Problem is, that when clicking on the second TabbarItem, the title changes like I want it to. But when getting back to the first tab, the title does not change back. I think I would need to set the title in a method like `onResume()` (android inspired). How do I do this in ios programming?

Comment: use [`viewWillAppear`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear)

Comment: @Scriptable i think he want to change title of second tab when he change it back to first tab he already mentioned that title is changing as he wants but not chnaging when he goes to first tab

Comment: @DevilDecoder I want to change the navigationtitle. It should be different for both tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make something the delegate of your tab bar controller. `UITabBarControllerDelegate` has a method, `tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)`, which is called whenever a tab is selected. You can change the title there.

An alternative (and probably better) suggestion, based on your comment above is to have the tab bar controller as the root view controller, and have each tab be a navigation controller which holds your content view controller. This way you're showing a different navigation controller for each tab, and it will probably make your onward development a lot simpler.

Comment: that may be to tedious work to do because you have check for controllers and find the controller to change title

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in `viewWillAppear`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.title = "Title"
}
```

Comment: i think he want to change title of second tab when he change it back to first tab he already mentioned that title is changing as he wants but not chnaging when he goes to first tab

Comment: I tried this, but then the title does not change when opening the second tab.